# Correlation between DHCP and ARP

Tags: dhcp, wireshark, arp

Can someone explain why there are so many ARP packets broadcasted from my client? And why is looking for my DHCP server?

[image]

Comment: Your picture doesn't allow for much in terms of interpretation, but ARP calls are made in your local loop, and don't go anywhere outside your network. Basically, it's your NIC(s) polling MAC addresses over your LAN to check if everyone's accounted for. Have you enabled shared folders on this PC? Do you access distant folders on your LAN from this PC? If you disable IPv6 altogether, you should see the list reduced by half.

Comment: Onu - the screenshot just confirms that all is working as designed. your PC is looking for an DHCP server as your NIC is asking for it - and uses broadcast and unicast during the DORA process (Discovery/Offer/Request/ACK)

@Didier - the screenshot does NOT show any IPv6 traffic, only IPv4 (L3) and ARP (L2)

Comment: So basically all my NICs (in this case 5) are asking for the MAC address of the DHCP server

Comment: yes, DHCP is set as default for NICs - there are exceptions of course (server setups eg)